# Recording Voice JAVAFX

Tags: java, javafx, record, microphone, voice

I´m here again to request your great Help.

I´m Trying to record voice from the microphone using a code from Internet.

this is the configuration to the audio format:

```
public class microfono {

    File wavFile = new File("C:\\NXB\\Kamui\\img\\audio.wav");
    AudioFileFormat.Type fileType = AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE;
    TargetDataLine line;

    AudioFormat getAudioFormat() {
        float sampleRate = 16000;
        int sampleSizeInBits = 8;
        int channels = 2;
        boolean signed = true;
        boolean bigEndian = true;
        AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(sampleRate, sampleSizeInBits,
                                             channels, signed, bigEndian);
        return format;
    }



public void StartRecording(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

    try {
        AudioFormat format = getAudioFormat();
        DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);

        // checks if system supports the data line
        if (!AudioSystem.isLineSupported(info)) {
            System.out.println("Error");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        line = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
        line.open(format);
        line.start();   // start capturing

        System.out.println("Startig...");

        AudioInputStream ais = new AudioInputStream(line);

        System.out.println("Start recording...");

        // start recording
        AudioSystem.write(ais, fileType, wavFile);

    } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

The code a this moment start recording indefinitely,if i stop the program the record is saved as .wav file in the path,but I need the way to stop that recording any time saving the wav file.

I tried this way but the program stops

```
   void finish() {

        line.stop();
        line.close();
        System.out.println("Finished");
    }
```

[image: thisin the error when y click the stop button]
thanks in advance for you help.

Comment: Why not create a `Button` or two to stop and start the process.

Comment: yes ,I have the start and stop buttons.The start button ,stars the recording.But if i click the stop button the program crashes. The start button is associated to StartRecording (); and stop to finish();

Comment: What does “the program crashes” mean?  Are you getting an exception?  If you are, edit your question and add the *entire stack trace* of that exception to your question, including all “Caused by” sections.

Comment: The recording is basically a long-running task that's freezing the GUI.

Comment: I don't have a mic to test this code. Let me know if it works.

Comment: VGR I´m added the image, i´m not getting any exception.

Comment: I deleted my answer since it's not working properly.

Comment: thanks. i´m trying to resteat the thread ,maybe it can solve the exeption.

Comment: Let me know if the update fixed your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made the `JavaSoundRecorder` extend `Task`. Now it should record in the background.

**JavaSoundRecorder Class:**

```
import java.io.*;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

/**
 * A sample program is to demonstrate how to record sound in Java author:
 * www.codejava.net
 * http://www.codejava.net/coding/capture-and-record-sound-into-wav-file-with-java-sound-api
 */
public class JavaSoundRecorder extends Task<Void>
{

    // record duration, in milliseconds
    static final long RECORD_TIME = 60000;  // 1 minute

    // path of the wav file
    File wavFile = new File("RecordAudio.wav");

    // format of audio file
    AudioFileFormat.Type fileType = AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE;

    // the line from which audio data is captured
    TargetDataLine line;

    @Override
    protected Void call() throws Exception
    {
        try {
            AudioFormat format = getAudioFormat();
            DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);

            // checks if system supports the data line
            if (!AudioSystem.isLineSupported(info)) {
                System.out.println("Line not supported");
                System.exit(0);
            }
            line = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
            line.open(format);
            line.start();   // start capturing

            System.out.println("Start capturing...");

            AudioInputStream ais = new AudioInputStream(line);

            System.out.println("Start recording...");

            // start recording
            AudioSystem.write(ais, fileType, wavFile);

        }
        catch (LineUnavailableException | IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Defines an audio format
     */
    AudioFormat getAudioFormat()
    {
        float sampleRate = 16000;
        int sampleSizeInBits = 8;
        int channels = 2;
        boolean signed = true;
        boolean bigEndian = true;
        AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(sampleRate, sampleSizeInBits,
                channels, signed, bigEndian);
        return format;
    }

    /**
     * Closes the target data line to finish capturing and recording
     */
    void finish()
    {
        line.stop();
        line.close();
        System.out.println("Finished");
    }

}
```

**Main Class:**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class JavaFXApplication58 extends Application
{

 JavaSoundRecorder javaSoundRecorder;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {       



        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Start");
        btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {        
            if (btn.getText().equals("Start")) {  
                javaSoundRecorder  = new JavaSoundRecorder();
                Thread thread = new Thread(javaSoundRecorder);
                thread.start();

                btn.setText("Stop");
            }
            else {
                javaSoundRecorder.finish();
                javaSoundRecorder.cancel();

                btn.setText("Start");                
            }
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks sedrik, code run once .If i click the button again i get an exeption.

Comment: Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException
 at java.lang.Thread.start(Unknown Source)
 at application.Main.lambda$0(Main.java:37)

Comment: I ran my program with no problems. I just could not record anything to the `wav` file because I have no mic on my work computer.

Comment: Are you using the exact code I posted or are you trying to incorporate it into your code?

Comment: yes ,the exact code .In the first time I can record , save the .wav file in the path and play it. but if i want record a new voice note .i get the exeption starting the new Thread. y copy and paste again but the still getting the exeption.

Comment: didi u try to recording again without close the program??

Comment: I will check it.

Comment: Thaks Sedrik .  it´s passible do a thread.stop?  or something like that?

Comment: I think you are right. The thread is still going. When I move the Thread inside the `Button` it does not throw the error, but also not completely working.

Comment: OKay Sedrik , now its working perfect, thankas a lot. I have now a little question.Do you suggest to save that audio clip in a database as Bloob? his size is 200 or 300 kb.or just save the path in the DB.

Comment: If the files are that small it probably doesn't matter, but most would probably say path.